# How to process a 2D array such that if an element is repeated more than N times, next occurrences of said element fallback to the 2nd column

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to make a system such that if the number of `Category_Number` is above the maximum, the number switches to the second column, and so on.

For example, imagine I have this array of 'club choices', where each row is a submission, with first, second, and third choices:

```
array([first_choice, second_choice, third_choice])
```

And to track the applicants, we add a tracking number `id`:

```
array([(first_choice, id), (second_choice, id), (third_choice, id)], dtype=[('choice', np.int8),('id', np.int16)])
```

For simplicity's sake, we won't look at the `id`s for now. I want the 2nd/third choice of a former applicant to tally to the max before the first choices of the next applicants.

`arr['choice']`:

```
array([
       [3, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 2],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 3],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 3, 1],
       [0, 3, 2],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 3],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 0]
       ])
```

Now, I want to categorize the data such that if the amount of a particular club type is beyond a number, let's say, `7`, then that application's value is switched to the second column, like so:

```
array([
       [3, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 2],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 3],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 3, 1],
       [0, 3, 2],
       #Category 0 max
       [2, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 3],
       [1, 3],    #was [0, 1, 3]
       [3, 1, 0],
       [2, 3],    #was [0, 2, 3],
       #Category 2 would have continued, but due to the changes, it now stops here.
       [3, 2, 0],
       [],        #was [0, 2, 3], then became [2, 3], then became [3], but 3 is also full, so it is now empty. 
       [1, 0]     #was [2, 1, 0]
       ])
```

The final choices are simply the first column transposed.

I hope what I am attempting to do is understood. I'm not restricted to numpy, if another approach is faster, I'd accept it. I made a couple of attempts at this, but none of them got anywhere. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: In category 0, what happens if after the number 0 reaches max 7 and later on, the number 3 also reaches 0? Will it also be reduced to the next category?

Comment: Suppose type `0` and type `3` are at their max, and we have the application `[0, 3, 1]`. The array would become `[1]`. If `1` is also full, then it becomes `[]`, or `All full` or something. I really just need to find a solution to the sorting/filtering, I can worry about such things later.